# Testing digital transistor

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, testing

Is there any difference in testing procedure for digital transistors since there are resistors?

I'm trying to check a C114E transistor but I can't find a datasheet to affirm the pinout. Assuming that base is the center pin, I'm getting an identical diode drop both ways from the collector to emitter. Not sure if this is right though, as I've never checked one of these.

Comment: Find the appropriate datasheet! Digikey has several C114e listed. In the old days, when transistors were in cans, it was safe to assume that the middle pin was the base. Now, bad assumption.

Comment: I haven't drawn any conclusions yet or I wouldn't be asking. I was mainly asking about the test procedure for a digital transistor. Hence the title. I was saying, assuming just to pose the question of whether an identical diode drop from any pin to another might be normal with one of these.

Comment: Can't you apply 1v between pairs of terminals and measure the current? BE will conduct both ways, BC only one way, CE neither. Ah, yes the base to emitter resistor will bypass the reverse be junction so CE will conduct one way as well...

Comment: Turns out the outside pins are BE so this one goes back to work.

Answer (score 1):

The diode drops usually indicate the B-E and B-C junctions of a BJT. Testing beyond that is best done with a component checker, like the one offered by [Kuman](http://www.kumantech.com/kuman-mega-328-graphic-transistor-tester-npn-pnp-diodes-triode-capacitor-esr-scr-mosfet-resistor-inductance-checker-k77_p0388.html):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "digital" transistor. Some are optimized for switching and others for analog (audio and video), but most are pretty much general purpose.

(edit) I see that these are internally biased types. It would be interesting to see how the component checker would analyze these.

https://www.rohm.com/electronics-basics/transistors/principles-digital-transistors

https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/small-signal-transistors-diodes/bipolar-transistor/general-purpose-and-digital-transistors/

Comment: Digital has resistors integrated to bias and prevent unwanted biasing.

Comment: I guess I should have searched for the term. https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/small-signal-transistors-diodes/bipolar-transistor/general-purpose-and-digital-transistors/ and https://www.rohm.com/electronics-basics/transistors/principles-digital-transistors

Comment: Yeah, I just learned of these while checking a reset circuit. I do have a device like the one you linked but I never use it. Would be worth a look though.

Comment: I knew them with the name "pre-biased".